# If I call api gateway apis from a ec2 instance with role, can AWS automatically handle the IAM authorization?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I want to call api gateway from our own backend which is a ECS cluster, and I want to use IAM authorization, is there any way to not manually sign the request using Access Key and Secret Key?

For example when Lambda call KMS to decrypt environment variables, no need to configure the AWS SDK. Wondering if there's similar thing for API gateway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is definitely possible, even more - it's a security best practice. You can assign IAM roles to all computing services of AWS: Lambda, EC2, ECS, Beanstalk etc. On ECS you can assign IAM roles to your tasks.

It gives a great benefit, which is well described in official docs:

> Benefits of Using IAM Roles for Tasks
>
> **Credential Isolation**: A container can only retrieve credentials for the IAM role that is defined in the task definition to which it belongs; a container never has access to credentials that are intended for another container that belongs to another task.
>
> **Authorization**: Unauthorized containers cannot access IAM role credentials defined for other tasks.
>
> **Auditability**: Access and event logging is available through CloudTrail to ensure retrospective auditing. Task credentials have a context of taskArn that is attached to the session, so CloudTrail logs show which task is using which role.

This link will help you: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-iam-roles.html